# Changing port 80 to 8080 in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, port, namevirtualhost

I'm trying to change the port used by a website from 80 to 8080.

Here is my `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080
Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

Here is my VirtualHost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@foo.com
  ServerName  www.foo.com
  ServerAlias foo.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/foo.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

`netstat -lntp` output:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080       :::*              LISTEN      7267/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::80         :::*              LISTEN      7267/apache2
```

When I restart apache using the port `8080` in my VirtualHost, the website goes down (could not connect to website error in chrome), if I change back to port `80`, all works correctly again.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

The host it's a linode machine with Debian 7.

Also I do not have SElinux enabled.

The `/etc/hosts` config:

```
127.0.0.1   <foo.com> <serverhostname>
127.0.1.1   debian

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I think the port 8080 it's correctly open, here is the output of `iptables -L -n -v`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  467 36136 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
 103K   11M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  600 35296 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
   30  1532 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
   42  2308 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
 6860  411K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
   44  2848 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  860 57824 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "iptables denied: "
  968 67687 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

`curl -v http://localhost:8080` output:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2013 09:58:08 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14
< X-Pingback: http://www.foo.com/xmlrpc.php
< Location: http://localhost/
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Are they...going to http://yoursite.com:8080 ?

Comment: No, it also won't work specifying the port in the url.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe Port 8080 is blocked by iptables. Use `iptables -L -n -v` to see if iptables is enabled and effectively blocking packets to port 8080.

Answer (score 3):

what distro are you running?
You may have SElinux enabled, which is denying your requests.

Check if SElinux is enbaled

```
# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

If the current mode is enforcing try to disable it during troubleshooting:

```
#setenforce 0
```

If it's working now you have to create a custom SElinux policy via `audit2allow`.

Answer (score 3):

From your netstat output it looks like port 8080 is listening on ipv6.
Are you using ipv6 to connect?

Is httpd listening on ipv4?

Can you run `netstat -lntp|grep 80` and show us all of the output instead of just pasting in the bit you think is relevant.

Comment: Running that netstat command returns only the two lines I've already posted.

Comment: Looks like you are only listening on IPv6.

Do you have IPv6 records for the server's name in DNS?
Or maybe /etc/hosts?

Comment: If you want to use IPv4 and you only have 1 IPv4 IP on the host then try replacing the VirtualHost and NameVirtualHost directives with that IP.
Or turn off ipv6 if you are not really using it.

Comment: If you look at your curl command above you will see it is connectiong on the IPv6 localhost. That(presumably) works, because that IPv6 IP (i.e. ::1 )is listening and is probably resolvable via /etc/hosts. So curl works because it is using ipv6.

Comment: I use a standard linode configuration for the DNS, as explained here: https://library.linode.com/dns-manager I've updated the post with the complete hosts file.

Comment: I can't tell anything about your DNS unless you tell me what your domain/hostname is (then I could do an nslookup), or unless you give me access to your linode control panel. I.e. you're gonna have to work out if DNS is the problem or not.
Are you actually intending to use IPv6?
If you are not I suggest you just turn it off.
And turn on IPv4.

Comment: also can you give us the output to "ifconfig -a" that will show us if there is an ipv4 interface configured and if there are any ipv6 interfaces configured other than localhost.
Can you ping you servername.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following  workaround,

- check apache configuration

  apachectl configtest
- test the page from the server itself and check HTTP output

  wget -O - "localhost"
- check apache error_log to what kind of error are you getting, probably a configuration on your website is not allowing port 8080
- try use only port 8080 to see what happens

  NameVirtualHost *:8080
  Listen 8080
- create only a VirtualHost listening on port 8080

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see that port is open.
What happend with

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080
```

?

Comment: As you could see your server returns header
"Location: http://localhost/"
So your browser trying to fetch content from http://localhost/, located at port 80. 

Is it a normal situation? Looks like there is a code, checking fqdn. Maybe you need to change any setting in site code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain your problem is that apache is listening on ipv6 at least for ::1 .

Can you please let me know if you want to use ipv4, ipv6 or both?

Please run the following and paste in the output:

```
ifconfig -a
```

That should show us all the IP addresses that are running on interfaces.

Assuming you are using `http://<servername>.<foo.com>` as the URL in chrome then please also run these commands are paste in the command and output:

```
dig <servername>.<foo.com>
dig <servername>
dig -t A <servername>.<foo.com>
dig -t A <servername>
dig -t AAAA <servername>.<foo.com>
dig -t AAAA <servername>
```

I'm assuming you want to use ipV4 not ipv6.
If that is the case try this:

Change your /etc/hosts to look like this:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
10.0.0.1 <servername>.<foo.com> <servername>

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

But replace the 10.0.0.1 with your ipv4 address.
Then restart apache.
And try again with your browser and with curl.

With curl try `localhost` and `<servername>.<foo.com>`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your curl test to localhost apache is listening to 8080 and responding although redirecting you with a 301 to http:// localhost/ but that seems to come from the default site.

As per your apache confing you are configuring a named virtual host, with ServerName www.foo.com

Try:

```
$ telnet localhost 8080
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.foo.com
```

Ending with two line returns. If that is returning content it means that server configuration is working fine. So your problem is between you and your server.